# Current Time in DateTime PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

Is this the correct way to get the current time in PHP using DateTime?

```
$currenttime = new DateTime();
$currenttime2 = $currenttime->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: Um, did you try it? Did it look correct?

Comment: You'll probably want to prefix it with `date_default_timezone_set("America/New York");` or whatever your timezone is. Other than that it should be fine. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: yes its correct way, `new DateTime();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it like this

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: but thats not DateTime right? because i need to compare it with another DateTime() object...

Comment: If you want to compare, then you must use $currenttime, don't recreate $currenttime2 as that is a string, not an object. $currenttime = new DateTime(); creates a DateTime object with the current time as default.

Answer (score 0):

This will set the time based on your date time settings in php.ini. Do a var_dump of $currenttime after creation to see what I mean. You may also use microtime(true); to obtain a unix timestamp, which can be converted using other functions.